# Checking a value of an object in a running process

Tags: python, python-2.7

In this easy example how can I access the value of a counter object while the process is still running?

```
import multiprocessing
import time

class Counter(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.value = 0

  def update(self):
    self.value += 1

def job(Counter):
  while True:
    counter.update()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  counter = Counter()
  p = multiprocessing.Process(target=job,args=(counter,)
  p.start()
  time.sleep(10)
  # I want to check the value of the counter object here
  p.terminate()
```

Comment: you will have to use `multiprocessing.Queue()` to send data from one process to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `multiprocessing.Queue()` or `multiprocessing.Pipe()` to communicate between processes.

`multiprocessing.Pipe()` creates two endpoints `conn_1`, `conn_2` and you have to use one of them in main process and second in subprocess.

Use `poll()` to check if there is something in pipe and then you can use `recv()` to receive data. (if you use directly `recv()` then it will block program till you send something to pipe).

Now you can use `send()` to send message with result.

Here I use `conn_2` in `job()`

```
import multiprocessing
import time

class Counter(object):

  def __init__(self):
    self.value = 0

  def update(self):
    self.value += 1

def job(counter, conn):
  while True:
    counter.update()
    if conn.poll():
        print('job:', conn.recv())
        conn.send(counter.value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  conn_1, conn_2 = multiprocessing.Pipe()

  counter = Counter()

  p = multiprocessing.Process(target=job, args=(counter, conn_2))
  p.start()

  time.sleep(2)

  # I want to check the value of the counter object here
  conn_1.send('give me result')
  print('result:', conn_1.recv())

  p.terminate()
```

Here I use `conn_2` directly in class

```
import multiprocessing
import time

class Counter(object):

  def __init__(self, conn):
    self.conn = conn
    self.value = 0

  def update(self):
    self.value += 1

    if self.conn.poll(): # if message from main process
        print('Counter:', self.conn.recv()) 
        self.conn.send(self.value)

def job(counter):
  while True:
    counter.update()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  conn_1, conn_2 = multiprocessing.Pipe()

  counter = Counter(conn_2)

  p = multiprocessing.Process(target=job, args=(counter,))
  p.start()

  time.sleep(2)

  conn_1.send('give me result')
  print('result:', conn_1.recv())

  p.terminate()
```

Answer (score -1):

You could consider attaching a debugger (such as the PyDev debugger, GDB or others) to the running process. You can then freeze the process with a breakpoint and inspect state.